# WPFMediaKit sample camera orientation/rotation not working

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-mediakit

I have a big problem with camera orientation/rotation when using the Codeplex WPFMediaKit VideoCaptureElement sample on a tablet PC running Windows 8.1. The image below was captured when the tablet orientation is vertical:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vss1V.jpg

But when the tablet is turned horizontally, the system rotates the image over again.

I am developing on Windows 7 using VS2013 C# .NET 4.0. Maybe someone has a hint or a sample from a solution.  I have already tried the example at Codeplex:

```
<WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement.LayoutTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
</WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement.LayoutTransform>
```

But the above workaround doesn't really help, as it mixes up everything.